# Reload provider within a submodule in Terraform

Tags: azure, kubernetes, terraform

Is it possible to reload a provider from within a submodule?

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    kubernetes = {
      source  = "hashicorp/kubernetes"
      version = "2.13.0"
    }
  }
}
#Problem: Loads kubeConfig before AKS is deployed
provider "Kubernetes" {
  config_path = "~/.kube/config"
}

module "deploy" {
  source = "./modules/deploy"
}

module "configure" {
#Solution: Force submodule to reload provider data
  source = "./modules/configure"
  depends_on = [
    module. Deploy
  ]
}
```

**Context**: I have Terraform module that contains two submodules; deploy and configure. Deploys creates a set of infrastructure to Azure and the other configures it.

I'm using `depends_on` to wait for the deploy module to finish before running the configure module.

That, however, makes me declare the provider blocks in the root module, which causes the Kubernetes provider to load before the local configuration has been updated. And that breaks configure module's logic.

Comment: could you clarify, maybe with an example?

Comment: Not a problem, I updated the question. Please lmk if that helps. :)

Comment: much clearer ... and indeed, I'm not sure what to answer. It would be easier to split this in two: call your module deploying EKS with plan/apply, and then plan the configure module (or: first bootstrap cluster with `-target=module.deploy`? might still want to init kube provider, not sure). The way we do this, with my current customer, is that we developped our own kubernetes provider which doesn't suffer from this constraint -- kube client is initialized during bootstrap, and that's good enough to then create new resources / plan phase does not query the API creating resources).

Comment: I found out that the hashicorp/Kubernetes provider was the problem. For some reason it loads the kubeconfig into the state and uses that information when calling resources. So, I replaced the steps that use that provider with local-exec. Thanks so much for the reply. :)

Comment: @joshduffney Are you going to post your solution as an answer?